# Facebook Scores API only shows me

Tags: swift, facebook-ios-sdk

I have two users logged in with publish_actions set to friends but on both users /appID/scores only returns one user's scores. Both are posting scores successfully.

Here is the posting code:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(
            graphPath: "/me/scores",
            parameters: ["score" : finalScore], HTTPMethod: "POST").startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                }

                NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().postNotificationName(SPostedScoreNotification, object: nil)

                complete()
        }
```

And here is the retrieving code:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
        FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "/" + appID + "/scores", parameters: ["fields" : "user,score"]).startWithCompletionHandler { (connection, result, error) in
            var fbScores = [FBScore]()

            guard
                let validResult = result,
                let data = validResult["data"] as? [[String : AnyObject]]
                else {
                    complete(fbScores)
                return
            }

            for scoreData in data {
                if let fbScore = FBScore(attributes: scoreData) {
                    if NSCalendar.currentCalendar().isDateInToday(fbScore.date) {
                        fbScores.append(fbScore)
                    }
                }
            }

            complete(fbScores)
        }
    })
```

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out.

1. You must request public_profile and user_friends first and then publish_actions. I was only requesting publish_actions.
2. publish_actions must not be set to only_me.